# Usage of SIM card GlobalPlatform keys in field

Tags: smartcard, javacard, ota, sim-card, globalplatform

**Question 1**. When a SIM manufacture personalizes a SIM card and then the mobile operator hand it over to an end user, are there any usage for GlobalPlatform (GP) keys (ENC,MAC,KEK,...)?

As long as I know the SIM file structure or its applets are accessible by (KID/KIC/KIK) over OTA RFM and RAM. So there is no need to have GP keys when SIM is in hands of customers.

Are there anywhere special (e.g. during OTA interactions that we require GP keys or not)? As I understood correctly, GP keys are usable when we physically can access a SIM card and we can directly send APDUs to the SIM. Am I right?

**Question 2**. Is it possible to access SIM/USIM file structure using global platform commands (e.g. is it possible to read record, read binary) using GP keys and access which ISD has? Typically file structure is accessible based on access conditions defined in 3GPP TS 51.011/ETSI TS 151 011 using PIN and ADM keys. But is it possible using GP keys and access which ISD has?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Q1:

I'm doing consulting for a MNO. All our plastic SIM cards are only using SCP80 (the OTA mechanism supporting [SMS, CAT_TP, TCP, BIP](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/102200_102299/102225/09.00.00_60/ts_102225v090000p.pdf)) and more recent versions are also supporting SCP81 (OTA using HTTPs using a pre-shared TLS keys  [GlobalPlatform RAM](https://globalplatform.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/GPC_2.2_B_RAM_over_HTTP_v1.1.1.pdf)). The SCP02 and SCP03 keys are rotated and not used. When using [eSIM](https://trustedconnectivityalliance.org/technology_overview/esim/) SCP03 is not even enabled in our case.

Q2:

No. But you can use OTA messages with e.g. SCP80 and wrap the read APDUs into [RFM](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/102200_102299/102226/16.00.00_60/ts_102226v160000p.pdf). With SCP02 /SCP03 this is not directly possible. But you could install an applet using SCP02/SCP03 with access to the [file system](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/131100_131199/131130/08.01.00_60/ts_131130v080100p.pdf) and use this as tunnel if you do not have the ADMs.